# How to limit the number of items from an observablecollection databinded listbox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, listbox-control

Here is how it goes. I have a viewmodel where I call a webclient and populate an observable collection with items. I need to have two different listboxes in two different pages but with the same ItemsSource from the viewmodel. How can I limit the number of items in one of the two listboxes without affect the other? I tried to use .Take(limit) into the viewmodel where the items are being created but that affects both listboxes.

Update

The viewmodel

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        this.Mainlist = new CollectionViewSource();

    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }
    public CollectionViewSource Mainlist { get; set; }

    void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           ...............
            //Ignore the dummy data in foreach loop. Just for showcase.

            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                //Items creation

                this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel()
                { LineOne = item });
            }

            this.Mainlist.Source = App.ViewModel.Items;
            this.Mainlist.Filter += (s, a) => 
                a.Accepted = App.ViewModel.Items.IndexOf((ItemViewModel)a.Item) < 10;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    } 

    .....................
}
```

On the View's side

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;
        list.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.Mainlist.View;
    }
```

**Update 2**

Another option that I found (without using the `CollectionViewSource`) is to make a new `public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Mainlist { get; private set; }` and use one more

```
            foreach (var item in Items.Take(limit))
            {
                //Items creation

                this.Mainlist.Add(new ItemViewModel()
                { LineOne = item });
            }
```

in order to populate the ObservableCollection and bind the listbox to Mainlist. That is working but also I think that is poor practice because in that way I have duplicated data. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource) and add filtering logic to limit the number of items shown. For example, if you wanted to show only 100 items:

```
var cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
cvs.Source = myList;  //the raw list from the viewmodel
cvs.Filter += (s, a) => a.Accepted = myList.IndexOf(a.Item) < 100;
listBox2.ItemsSource = cvs.View;
```

EDIT: based on posted code

When you set the `Mainlist.Source`, that changes the `Mainlist.View` as well. So setting the `list.ItemsSource` in the `MainPage` constructor is useless (besides, the `View` property is most likely `null` at that time anyway).  In order to fix your issue, you should move these following lines to the `MainViewModel` constructor:

```
this.Mainlist.Source = App.ViewModel.Items;
this.Mainlist.Filter += (s, a) => 
            a.Accepted = App.ViewModel.Items.IndexOf((ItemViewModel)a.Item) < 10;
```

That way, you only set the `Source` once, and the `View` doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks @Eren but in my case "myList" is "App.ViewModel.Items" which is the observable collection so I am getting an error at the IndeOf expression.

Comment: That should be fine since `ObservableCollection` does have an `IndexOf` method. What is the error?

Comment: The error is Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'ItemViewModel'

Comment: I see. Try `myList.IndexOf((ItemViewModel)a.Item)`.

Comment: I just updated my first post with some code. I tried to make a new property where I can store these items and bind against it from the View. Please take a look.

Comment: Hmm I tried that way also (move that snippet to viewmodel constructor) but the app crashes anexpectedly. Tried to debug and the problem seems to be at the line "this.Mainlist.Source = App.ViewModel.Items;" Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably keep it simple, and head more in the direction of your original approach, doing something like:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    _items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
}

public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { 
    get {return _items;} 
    private set {_items = value;} 
}
private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _items;

private int _items_to_show_on_second_list = 10;

public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> ItemsLimit { 
    get {return _items.Take(_items_to_show_on_second_list);} 
    private set {_items = value;} 
}
```

Note that you might not want to set anything on the 2nd observable collection, up to you.

The benefits are that you're not changing your logic, you can still have readable code (using the `Take()` and a meaningful variable name to avoid the `magic number` that will eventually be abused.